# [LWC]Could you tell me which frame this .js code is using? lwc component hoverableLink

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

I want to make a lwc component same as hoverableLink.

[image]

This is the "hoverableLink" component code I get from the lwc source files. Unfortunately I can barely understand it.

If I want to understand the whole js code, how it works and how to code something similar, which frame should I learn? Is it JQuery? Or the "component" concept comes from ES6 and this is just simple Js code?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

```
(function s() {
return(funct(ion() {
    $A.componentService.addModule'markup:/r/force:hoveableLink', 'force/hoverableLink', ['lwc', 'lightning/buttonIcon', '@salesforce/label/InlineEdit.preview', 'lightning/utils', 'lightning/datatableKeyboardMixins'], function(e, o, i, t, s) {
        o=o&&Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o, "default")?o.default: o, i=i&&Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(i, "default")?i.default:i;

        var n=[function(e, o, i) {
            return[i?":host{display:block}":[e, "{display:block}"].join(""), ".hide-hover-icon", o, "{position:absolute;clip:rect(1px 1px 1px 1px);clip-path:polygon(0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0)}a", o, "{text-decoration:none;display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle}a", o, " span", o, "{border-bottom:var(--lwc-borderWidthThin,1px) dotted;display:inline}.flex-wrap-ie11", o, "{overflow:hidden}"].join("")
        }

        ];

        function l(e, i, t, s) {
            const {
                d: n, h:l, b:h, c:r
            }

            =e, {
                _m0: a, _m1:c, _m2:u, _m3:d, _m4:v, _m5:w, _m6:m, _m7:p, _m8:g, _m9:y
            }

            =s;

            return[i.hasValue?l("div", {
                classMap: {
                    "slds-grid":  !0
                }

                , key:3
            }

            , [l("a", {
                className:i.computedAnchorClass, attrs: {
                    href: i.href, tabindex:"0"
                }

                , key:1, on: {
                    mouseover: a||(s._m0=h(i.handleMouseover)), mouseout:c||(s._m1=h(i.handleMouseout)), mousedown:u||(s._m2=h(i.handleMousedown)), click:d||(s._m3=h(i.handleClick)), dblclick:v||(s._m4=h(i.handleDoubleClick)), focus:w||(s._m5=h(i.handleFocus)), blur:m||(s._m6=h(i.handleBlur))
                }
            }

            , [l("span", {
                key: 0
            }

            , [n(i.text)])]), r("lightning-button-icon", o, {
                className:i.computedPreviewIconClass, props: {
                    iconName: "utility:preview", variant:"bare", alternativeText:i.computedPreviewTitle
                }

                , key:2, on: {
                    click: p||(s._m7=h(i.handlePreviewIconClick)), focus:g||(s._m8=h(i.handlePreviewIconFocus)), blur:y||(s._m9=h(i.handlePreviewIconBlur))
                }
            }

            , [])]):null]
        }

        var h=e.registerTemplate(l);

        l.stylesheets=[], n&&l.stylesheets.push.apply(l.stylesheets, n), l.stylesheetTokens= {
            hostAttribute: "force-hoverableLink_hoverableLink-host", shadowAttribute:"force-hoverableLink_hoverableLink"
        }

        ;

        class r extends(s.baseNavigation(e.LightningElement)) {
            constructor(...e) {
                super(...e), this.href=void 0, this.text="", this.shouldTruncate= !1, this.isFocusing= !1, this._showDelay=300, this._hideDelay=100, this.timeoutId=null, this.isHoverShowing= !1, this.shouldHidePreviewIconOnBlur= !1, this.shouldShowPreviewIconOnFocus= !0
            }

            notifyPanelClose() {
                this.isHoverShowing= !1
            }

            get hideDelay() {
                return this._hideDelay
            }

            get showDelay() {
                return this._showDelay
            }

            set showDelay(e) {
                const o=parseInt(e, 10);
                Number.isInteger(o)&&(this._showDelay=o)
            }

            set hideDelay(e) {
                const o=parseInt(e, 10);
                Number.isInteger(o)&&(this._hideDelay=o)
            }

            get computedPreviewIconClass() {
                return t.classSet("slds-shrink-none").add( {
                    "hide-hover-icon":  !this.isFocusing
                }

                )
            }

            get computedPreviewTitle() {
                return i.replace("{0}", this.text)
            }

            get computedAnchorClass() {
                return t.classSet("flex-wrap-ie11").add( {
                    "slds-truncate": this.shouldTruncate
                }

                )
            }

            get hasValue() {
                return ! !this.text
            }

            handleClick(e) {
                this.hideHoverWithDelay(e, 0)
            }

            handleDoubleClick(e) {
                this.showHoverWithDelay(e, {
                    enableFocusHoverPanelEventHandler:  !0, shouldReturnFocus: !0
                }

                , 0)
            }

            handleMouseover(e) {
                this.showHoverWithDelay(e, {
                    enableFocusHoverPanelEventHandler:  !1, shouldReturnFocus: !1
                }

                , this.showDelay)
            }

            handleMouseout(e) {
                this.hideHoverWithDelay(e, this.hideDelay)
            }

            handleMousedown() {
                this.shouldShowPreviewIconOnFocus= !1
            }

            focus() {
                const e=this.template.querySelector("a");
                e&&e.focus()
            }

            handleFocus() {
                this.shouldShowPreviewIconOnFocus?this.isFocusing= !0: this.shouldShowPreviewIconOnFocus= !0
            }

            handleBlur(e) {
                this.isHoverShowing||this.hideHoverWithDelay(e, 0), this.isFocusing= !1
            }

            handlePreviewIconClick(e) {
                this.showHoverWithDelay(e, {
                    enableFocusHoverPanelEventHandler:  !0, shouldReturnFocus: !0
                }

                , 0), this.shouldHidePreviewIconOnBlur= !1, e.stopPropagation()
            }

            handlePreviewIconBlur() {
                this.shouldHidePreviewIconOnBlur&&(this.isFocusing= !1)
            }

            handlePreviewIconFocus() {
                this.isFocusing= !0, this.shouldHidePreviewIconOnBlur= !0
            }

            showHoverWithDelay(e, o, i) {
                this.cancelUpcomingTimeout(), this.isHoverShowing&&this.hideHover();

                const t=e.target, s=Object.assign( {
                    reference: t
                }

                , o);

                this.timeoutId=setTimeout(()=> {
                    this.showHover(s)
                }

                , i)
            }

            hideHover() {
                const e=new CustomEvent("hidehover", {
                    bubbles:  !0, composed: !0, cancelable: !0
                }

                );
                this.dispatchEvent(e)
            }

            hideHoverWithDelay(e, o) {
                this.cancelUpcomingTimeout(), this.isHoverShowing&&(0===o?this.hideHover():this.timeoutId=setTimeout(()=> {
                    this.hideHover()
                }

                , o))
            }

            showHover(e) {
                const o=new CustomEvent("showhover", {
                    bubbles: !0, composed: !0, cancelable: !0, detail: {
                        hoverPanelConfig: e
                    }
                }

                );
                this.dispatchEvent(o), this.isHoverShowing= !0
            }

            cancelUpcomingTimeout() {
                this.timeoutId&&clearTimeout(this.timeoutId), this.timeoutId=null
            }
        }

        return e.registerDecorators(r, {
            publicProps: {
                href: {
                    config: 0
                }

                , text: {
                    config: 0
                }

                , shouldTruncate: {
                    config: 0
                }

                , hideDelay: {
                    config: 3
                }

                , showDelay: {
                    config: 3
                }
            }

            , publicMethods:["notifyPanelClose", "focus"], track: {
                isFocusing: 1
            }

            , fields:["_showDelay", "_hideDelay", "timeoutId", "isHoverShowing", "shouldHidePreviewIconOnBlur", "shouldShowPreviewIconOnFocus"]
        }

        ), e.registerComponent(r, {
            tmpl: h
        }

        )
    }

    );
}

)})()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is obfuscated JavaScript "LWC compiler" output. LWCs are "compiled" from source that is a combination of JavaScript, CSS and HTML, turning this into obfuscated JavaScript.

There's no point trying to understand it for writing your own code; that's like trying to reverse-engineer C++ from assembler. Instead you should look at the [Lightning Design System blueprints](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/tooltips/) and work your way from there.

The [popover blueprint](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/popovers/) seems like a fair starting point for your requirement.

For how to write LWCs, start from the [introductory developer documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.get_started_introduction).